# Leave request template for SharePoint online

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online

Anyone come across an online Leave request template I can use with Office 365?

Don't mind if custom solution , I can do myself

Answer (score 2):

A leave request template basically consists of a calendar list tied to a simple workflow.

1. Create new custom list
2. Add the list columns you need (i.e. Start Date, End Date, Reasoning, Manager, Status - Approve/Reject, Comments)

Then add a custom view to restrict employees from seeing others requests:

1. List Settings > Create New View
2. Select "Standard View"
3. Give the view a name
4. Select list columns & reorder them
5. Scroll down to input filter settings
6. Show only items where Created by = [Me] OR Manager = [Me]
7. Click Save

Finally, make the workflow (at my work we use Nintex Workflows for this):

1. Workflow settings > Start automatically when new items are created.
2. Add Workflow Action > Update List
3. Update Manager list column to equal Manager (this pulls the creator's manager name from the directory into your list)
4. Add Workflow Action > Request Approval
5. Collect data from List Column > Manager
6. Add a workflow action under the Approved branch to notify the creator leave is approved and another action to update the Status column to "Approved".
7. Add a workflow action under the Rejected branch to notify the creator their request was rejected + why and another action to update the Status column to "Rejected".
8. Name & Publish your workflow.

Done.

Comment: Thanks for this and i know we can customise one.Just looking out for templates that can be used in sharepoint online.Do you have these steps blogged somewhere

Comment: The steps I just described above? Unfortunately no, my website is currently a work in progress. I just wrote that off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Their is one i saw on the MSFT site, i dont wheather it will work with current o365 version or not.

[Absence Request and Vacation Schedule Management](http://www.techsolutions.net/AbsenceRequest.aspx)

there are other HR related templates also available.,

http://www.microsoft.com/government/en-us/campaigns/Pages/SharePoint-Templates.aspx

Comment: Thanks Robert will have a look.There is nothing really much on the store either.Guess its time to start thinking of some business

Comment: another code example if you interested to develop it...http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2013/11/10/answered-leave-request-for-sharepoint-o365-sample-on-msdn/

Comment: Wow Fabian.Thats close to what i needed.I do i add that to SharePoint online.Will read through though

Comment: Robert i tried using those template on my sharepoint online but didnt work.Thanks