# How to Develops Leave Request System For office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am new in office 365, Our requirement is to develop a **Leave Request System** in SharePoint online. Could please guide me how can i develop this?

please help me.

Comment: There are some paid SharePoint APP available in market. You can get some idea from that. [Time Off](https://store.office.com/time-off-manager-WA104379225.aspx?assetid=WA104379225)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to develop a Leave Request System, You need

1. Calaendar List
2. Workflow( approve / reject the request)

you can get the idea from these posts.

[Leave request template for SharePoint online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111003/leave-request-template-for-sharepoint-online)

[Leave request for SharePoint O365 Sample on MSDN](http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2013/11/10/answered-leave-request-for-sharepoint-o365-sample-on-msdn/)

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b8a1b75-9ad7-4ad8-a1fc-95deabf07ba2/infopathsharepoint-online-leave-request-for-dummies?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy